# Can I make a plugin to navigate the Web UI in Dynamics CRM

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I am following the tutorial in:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx
 to make a plugin for Dynamics CRM. It run on server side.

*The plug-in creates a task activity after a new account is created. The activity reminds the user to follow-up with the new account customer one week after the account was created.*

How can I extend this plugin to force the Web page to programmingly open the task that have just created?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the plugin runs server side and cannot interact with the user interface.

You would need to do something like add JavaScript that recognises when the plugin has completed and redirects the user.

Comment: Thank James. Is there a way to insert a Javascript file that can be called when the page loaded? I see we can insert a Webresource into a form, but this webresoure only run when we open the form.

Comment: Yes, there is a JavaScript API you can use, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584(v=crm.5).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate more.